# Change button color and icon in future gridView

Tags: flutter, dart, gridview

I have a gridview contained in Future Builder, and I'd like to have this kind of rendering.
As you can see, when an element is selected, the color change, the icon too and obviously I add it to a Set (to have only single element)

[image]

Titles come from an API called.

So I did something like this :

```
FutureBuilder<List<ProjectTheme>> (
 future: themeColorList.buildTheme(),
 builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<ProjectTheme>> snapshot) {
   if(snapshot.hasData)
     return GridView.builder(
       itemCount: themes.length,
       gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
       itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
         var theme = snapshot.data[index];
           return Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                 Positioned(
                   child: ButtonTheme(
                   height: height * 0.15,
                   minWidth: width * 0.4,
                   child: RaisedButton(
                     shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                        color: selectedThemes.contains(theme.themeName) ? theme.themeColor = Colors.grey : theme.themeColor = theme.themeColor,
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            changeOneClickItemState(theme);
                          });
                        },
                     ),
                   ),
                 ),
                 Padding(
                   child: Align(
                     alignment: Alignment.center,
                     child: selectedThemes.contains(theme.themeName)? Icon(Icons.check):theme.themeIcon,
                   )
                 ),
              ],
            );
          }
        );
      }
  )
```

The selectedThemes is just the list where I add my selection.

And here is the method called in the onPressed button :

```
 void changeOneClickItemState(ProjectTheme theme) {
    pressed = !pressed;
    pressed ? selectedThemes.add(theme.themeName) : selectedThemes.remove(theme.themeName);
 }
```

So it worked approximately, but I need to tap several times on every element to see the element selected. It seems like the app is not reactive, and I think it's because takes times to check if element is in the list or not.
The fact is, I can't set "pressed ?" instead of "selectedTheme.contains(theme.themeName)" in the color property of my RaisedButton, because all of my buttons turn to grey. But I need to make it more reactive, because it's not acceptable for a client to tap on the button several times to make it work...

Do you have an idea on how can I solve this?

Comment: does your future builder take time to return the data

Comment: It is, and I added Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())) while waiting the grid is displayed

Comment: in this line: 
'theme.themeColor = Colors.grey : theme.themeColor = theme.themeColor' 
try: 'Colors.grey : theme.themeColor'
does it still have the same behavior?

Comment: Yes exactly the same

Comment: try to print selectedThemes and theme inside changeOneClickItemState when you click to see what's happening..

Comment: Actually, the printed element is not called each time I press a button. So... my theory is an issue with the Future Builder itself... I have to try to extract this part and construct the gridview after, once themeColorList.buildTheme() is already built

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sooooo, I finally find a way to make it.
As I said, the problem was the gridView were built inside the Future Builder.

So, I made a method where I built themes and called it in init.

```
List<ProjectTheme> projectThemes;

void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getThemes();
  buildThemes();
}

Future<List<ProjectTheme>> buildThemes() async {
  List<ProjectTheme> projectThemeList = await themeColorList.buildTheme();
  setState(() {
    this.projectThemes = projectThemeList;
  });

  return projectThemeList;
}
```

Then I built my Grid view as below after added a property "isPressed" to my class:

```
GridView.builder(
  itemCount: themes != null ? themes.length : 0,
  gridDelegate: new SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 2),
  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
      var theme = projectThemes[index];
      theme.isPressed = false;

      return projectThemes != null ? Stack(
           children: <Widget>[
              Positioned(
                child: ButtonTheme(
                   height: height * 0.15,
                   minWidth: width * 0.4,
                   child: RaisedButton.icon(
                   shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),

                   onPressed: () {
                     setState(() {
                       selectedThemes.contains(theme.themeName) ?
                       theme.isPressed = false :
                       theme.isPressed = true;

                       changeOneClickItemState(theme);
                     });
                   },
                   color: selectedThemes.contains(theme.themeName) ? Colors.grey : theme.themeColor,
                   icon: selectedThemes.contains(theme.themeName) ? Icon(Icons.check) : theme.themeIcon,
                   label: Text(''),
                 ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ) : Container(child: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()));
         }
       )
```

And changeOneClickItemState :

```
 void changeOneClickItemState(ProjectTheme theme) {
   theme.isPressed ? 
   selectedThemes.add(theme.themeName) : 
   selectedThemes.remove(theme.themeName);
 }
```

Maybe it would help someone one day !

Comment: Yes in 16 hours, I can't accept my own answer directly after it posted

Comment: Ah ok. Sorry didnt know